# Password Manager autofilling in installed applications

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing a password manager app. I need auto filling in login section of installed apps whereby I have got a list of all installed apps in my activity. On click in the list I want that particular item to auto fill its login section. I tried it using content provider, but all in vain.
Below is the code containing list of installed apps.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private PackageManager packageManager = null;
private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new LoadApplications().execute();
}


 @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

      ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        try {
            Intent intent = packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);
          //  displayAboutDialog();

            if (null != intent) {                   

                 startActivity(intent);
                //intent.FILL_IN_DATA; 

                 }

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        }

private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                  //  displayAboutDialog();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

   private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.list_row, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,
                    "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: I am newbee in android. Sorry if you could not understand my question. Just like lastpass i am trying my hand on similar application in android. I am trying to get autofilling in login section of installed apps as shown in list above in code.

Comment: That too is not a question. You may have better luck using an [Android developer support site](http://www.andglobe.com) that is in a language that is more comfortable for you. Otherwise, **what is your question**?

Comment: Its for the first time, so again sorry for that. While again let me try with it. List above shows all the installed apps in system, please let me know on click on apps like facebook(from list), i want to show a dialog which asks user to store username and password in my application database. Such that when user again open facebook(eg), should automatic get details filled up in login section. Its a password manager application. I hope i made it clear this time.
P.S# i tried